# Locate different generic services in one non generic Locator

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, service

I have various Services that implement

```
public interface IReceiver<PayLoad>
{
    string Name {get;}
    Task SendObjectContainerAsync(ObjectContainer<PayLoad> m);
    Task<ObjectContainer<PayLoad>> GetSnapshot();
}
```

For Example

```
public class Printer : IReceiver<TextDocument>
```

or

```
public class TextDocumentService : IReceiver<Letter>
```

Now I want to collect all instances of each IReceiver in one Controller, I could

```
public class Broker<Payload>
{
     List<IReceiver<Payload>> receivers;         
}
```

and initialize an Instance for each type of IReceiver and then DI it into the IReceivers to enable them to register and get the Instances from other places.

Is this a good way to handle different Services? I think it gets kind of messy with many Brokers and I would rather have something like

```
static void register<Payload>(IReceiver<Payload> RegisterMe)
```

and

```
static List<IReceiver<Payload>> getReceivers<PayLoad>()
```

But im not able to implement this Locator because I dont know how to administrate different generic Lists in one non generic class

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using a *Dependency Injection* framework you should be able to configure which receivers you want to particulary *inject* into specific `Broker<PayLoad>` instances.

In the other hand, you should practice *constructor injection*:

```
public class Broker<Payload>
{
     public Broker(IList<IReceiver<PayLoad>> receivers)
     {
          Receivers = receivers;
     }

     public IList<IReceiver<PayLoad>> { get; }
}
```

Now, the next issue is that you want a *broker* to handle more than a receiver type. So the easiest way will be a small refactor on your `IReceiver<PayLoad>` interface:

```
// No more PayLoad generic type parameter! Let's move it to
// the methods
public interface IReceiver
{
    string Name { get; }
    Task SendObjectContainerAsync<TPayLoad>(ObjectContainer<TPayLoad> m);
    Task<ObjectContainer<TPayLoad>> GetSnapshot<TPayLoad>();
}
```

Finally, your brokers will look as follows:

```
public class Broker
{
     public Broker(IList<IReceiver> receivers)
     {
          Receivers = receivers;
     }

     public IList<IReceiver> { get; }
}
```

### About the `Locator` thing

Are you going to implement a static service locator? Don't do this, it's considered an anti-pattern, because you're going to couple your components to *how they receive their dependencies* while you should avoid this.

Components should remain agnostic on how they get their dependencies, because this is a reponsibility of a higher layer, usually the IoC/DI container.

Also, it makes your code more test-friendly, because you can test your components without integrating the IoC/DI container, because you just expect constructor arguments.